# Open source backup software

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, backup

Can anyone recommend a software for windows 10 with a graphical user itnerface to create backups of my laptop hard drive to an external hard drive. Ideally, the software would be free and open source.

I've been using AOMEI Backupper which in general works satisfactory but I'd prefer open source software. Today I've tried DirSync which in general seems nice but apparently it works rather slow for folders with many (>1,000,000) files.

Comment: Thanks! One thing I forgot to ask: Are you talking about "syncing a disk" (i.e. only backing up data) – or should applications etc (maybe registry related stuff – I'm no Windows user, so I don't know exactly what specifics might be needed) be covered as well? Further, do you need a 1:1 solution (think: mirror) – or also incremental backups, point-in-time recovery etc?

Comment: Not open source, but have you looked at the File History functionality built into Windows 10 yet? If all you're looking for is just backing up personal files,it actually works remarkably well.

Comment: Didn't know that DirSync is open source, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Duplicati](https://www.duplicati.com/), it's free and open source (LGPL), [Source Code on Github](https://github.com/duplicati/duplicati). It supports a lot of backup endpoints including of course local external hard drives.

It has a user interface, works on Windows 10 and supports encryption.

Answer (score 0):

[DirSync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirSync_Pro) is good for backing up individual folders (including subfolders).